# I wanna stop direct access to and folder using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I wanna set up an download page.
I need to access those pages only through a login page and stop all the direct access to the download page path and also its files and again if anyone tries to access those pages directly then it should automatically *redirect to login page itself or else at least with a 404 error*.

How can I do all these in **.htaccess** file. It will be very much helpful in developing my website.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your all of your downloads are inside of a `downloads` directory, something like this should do the trick.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(?:www\.)?your.site.*
RewriteRule ^downloads\/?.* http://your.site/login [R=302,L]
```

Alternatively (and ideally) you should instead keep the pages outside of the site's root directory and download them through a proxy page.

Comment: it didn't work. But anyway thanks for your help coz I found the way how to make it work. It's from your idea.

Comment: sorry sir .. it worked perfectly fine... I am the one who made the mistake.. you are awesome...

Comment: But the only thing is i wanna avoid direct access only .. not from when it is linked from page

Comment: @KarthickK so if the user gets to it from a page it should load, but if they hit F5 it should redirect them to the login page?

Comment: yeah like that.

Comment: @KarthickK edited, this really is somewhat of a bad way to do this though, it would be better to serve all your downloads through a script that checks if the user is logged in.